# Is there any way to prevent a group from taking up multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a parent group, a child group, and child group of the first child group. From the images below, you can see that each group takes up multiple rows and it's taking up a lot of unnecessary space when running the report. Is there any way to make them not take up additional rows like that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not unnecessary space, you have created these Row Groups in this Matrix, The child groups will show under the parent groups otherwise the data will not make any sense. But if you dont want any child-parent grouping in rows than obviously it will show all in one row.

Comment: @M.Ali I've seen a report before that didn't have this issue. But I can't find it at the moment. So I know it can be done, I just don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

1. Delete the 3 columns on the left without deleting the groupings.
2. Delete the top 3 rows without deleting any groupings.
3. Right click on remaining cell and insert 3 columns to the left.

**Method 2:**

1. Split the Cells in Region, Area and Location by right clicking.
2. Delete the top 3 rows without deleting any groupings.

Comment: Method 1 worked for me. Wish I had seen this earlier. I deleted them on a whim and it worked when I added the column data.